# Area of Parametric Curves

Tags: calculus, area, parametric, parametrization

Compute, in terms of $A, B, h$, and $k$, the area enclosed by the curve defined by the parametric equations:

$x(θ)=Acosθ+h$

$y(θ)=Bsinθ+k \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $  for $0 ≤ \theta ≤ 2π$.

Since those equations obviously form an ellipse, I first tried using the formula $Area_{ellipse} = \pi r_1r_2$ and ended up with $AB \pi$, and that was apparently wrong.

Next, I tried to use the formula $\int_a^bg(t)f^\prime(t)dt$, ending up with the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}-AB*sin^2\theta-Aksin\theta \quad d\theta$ and the answer $-AB \pi$, which is also wrong.

Is there are formular or something that I'm missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note your two equations can be rearranged & summed to get $\left(\frac{x(\theta) - h}{A}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y(\theta) - k}{B}\right)^2 = 1$. This, as you stated, is an equation for an ellipse. As far as I can tell, the area should be $AB\pi$, as you stated. As you say "that was apparently wrong", what is the supposedly correct answer?

Comment: No idea. Webwork only ever lets us know if it's wrong. I'll only know the correct answer if I get it correct

Comment: I read in a comment on another one of the posts here a while back (I don't recall which one) that Webwork can quite often be "incorrect". However, I believe from the context this was to indicate that it just usually means you need to put your response into a form that Webwork expects, rather than less frequent occasions when it's just plain wrong. Did you get any kind of instructions, e.g., the format to use, for using Webwork?

Comment: Yes, our webwork is actually quite flexible and doesn't require simplifications and whatnot. Since our webwork is constantly monitored, I've never heard of it being incorrect. I think I might be misunderstanding the question

Comment: My suggested answer assumed that $AB$ is positive. However, since you haven't stated otherwise, it's possible that $A$ and $B$ have opposite signs. Thus, to handle this possibility, I believe the correct answer is something like $\left|AB\right|\pi$ instead. One more thing though, this also assumes that $A \neq 0$ and $B \neq 0$. This will likely not be an issue, but you may wish to mention it in your answer, to be completely thorough. I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, simply adding the absolute value sign worked! If you could type that down as an answer and explain why in a bit more detail, that would be marvelous! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to solve the issue for you. We have to be careful with our assumptions, as shown here. Also, as I stated in my answer (I trust I provided enough detail), I realized that $A$ and/or $B$ can be $0$, with the area still being given correctly. Thus, please ignore my earlier suggestion to include this restriction in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided equations are

$$x\left(\theta\right) = A \cos\theta + h \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$y\left(\theta\right) = B \sin\theta + k \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

where $0 ≤ \theta ≤ 2\pi$. As you've already correctly surmised, this is an equation of an ellipse, determined by, in \eqref{eq1}, subtracting $h$ & dividing by $A$ and, in \eqref{eq2}, subtracting $k$ & dividing by $B$, to get

$$\cos\theta = \frac{x\left(\theta\right) - h}{A} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$
$$\sin\theta = \frac{y\left(\theta\right) - k}{B} \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

Squaring both sides of each & adding, using that $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$, gives

$$ \left(\frac{x\left(\theta\right) - h}{A}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y\left(\theta\right) - k}{B}\right)^2 = 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

As can be seen, such as indicated in Wikipedia's [Ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), this is a general equation of an ellipse, with a center at $\left(h,k\right)$ and semi-major & semi-minor axes of $\left|A\right|$ and $\left|B\right|$. Note that since the axes are always non-negative values, and there was no stipulation that $A$ and $B$ are both positive, it's important to account for this issue by taking absolute values.

As for the area, it will thus be $\left|AB\right|\pi$, using absolute value signs here again since the area is always non-negative. One final thing to note is that if $A$ or $B$ are $0$, then \eqref{eq3} to \eqref{eq5} are invalid. Nonetheless, the answer for the area would still be valid. This is because $x\left(\theta\right)$ and/or $y\left(\theta\right)$ would just be a constant value, thus giving an "ellipse" with no width and/or height, so the resulting area would be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler:  Clearly the offsets $h$ and $k$ are irrelevant to the area.  The major and minor axes have effective "radii" of $A$ and $B$, so the area is $\pi |A B|$ (just to ensure the area is positive).